# How to alter .bst file to suit journal requirements

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to format my references to suit the journals' (Journal of Physical Chemistry B) requirements.  Their LaTeX template is not correct (frustrating!)  I have used the "latex makebst" command as others have suggested.

I have gotten this .bst file very close to the journal's requirements via "latex makebst".  However, there are a few minor details that the .bst file I created got wrong, and I am unable to redo by recompiling the .dbj file.

I am trying to follow the American Chemical Society as closely as I can so I don't have to type 200 references manually.  I would like to give this to the journal so they can post it to other authors so they don't have this difficulty in the future.

There are a few issues I wish to correct in the .bst file:

1. There is a comma after the last author in articles.
2. Page numbers for books are omitted.

How can I edit the .bst file to correct these two errors?  The .bst file is 1254 lines long.

Much appreciated and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to make your own `.bst` file? I've provided one for several years: the  `achemso` contains code and instructions for matching all of the ACS journal styles.

Comment: Regarding the second question: I'm pretty sure that there's a question in the `makebst` utilility that asks if you want to show page numbers for books. The default answer is "n"; you'd have to switch it to "y" to get page numbers shown for entries of type `@book`.

Comment: Can you post your bst file online so that one could take a look at its code?

Answer (score 1):

Many BibTeX users have encountered this same problem. There are a couple ways around this. Many journals require that users paste the contents of the BBL file into the main `*.tex` manuscript file, so that it needs to be compiled only with LaTeX and not BibTeX as well. For this case, users can manually edit the `\bibitem` entries to achieve the needed format.

However, this is not a very satisfying solution. The recently-developed [Bibulous project](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) provides an alternative. Since Bibulous' style templates are readily customized, it typically requires only a few minutes to develop a custom style that fits a journal requirements. For example, a journal that requires a list of author names followed by a title in quotes, a journal name in italics, a volume number in bold, an issue number in parentheses, a page range, and finally a year in parentheses, the template for an article entry would be

```
article = <au>, \enquote{<title>,} \textit{<journal>} \textbf{<volume>} (<issue>)...
          : [<startpage>--<endpage>|<startpage>|<eid>] (<year>).
```

One can also develop similar templates for any other entry types (`book`, `inproceedings`, etc) that are specified by the journal's requirements and the user's `*.bib` database file.